# Create new file with spaces from argument BASH

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

I need to create new file which contains spaces in it. And it is passed through the argument. This code below creates 2 sepate files. How to create 1 file which will contains space?

```
touch ""$meno""
```

Comment: Stop over-thinking the problem. `touch "$meno"` will do just fine.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this:

```
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
touch "$yourfile"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```bsh
$ spam="foo bar"
$ touch "$spam"
$ ls -l
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user   0 Mar 29 05:14 foo bar
```